# setTimeout not recalling function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have a list of images that I want to iterate through as a slideshow. I've set up a basic function to display an image then used `setTimeout` to recall the function and move onto the next image.

The function is only being called once and displays just the one image. I've checked the syntax of `setTimeout` I'm sure it's correct. Is there a fault in my code somewhere else that is causing this ?

```
<img id='screenImg' src='' height='300' width='450'/>

function slideshow() {

var screenImg = document.getElementById('screenImg');
var gradImg = ['images/grad1.jpg', 'images/grad2.jpg', 'images/grad3.jpg',   'images/grad4.jpg', 'images/grad5.jpg', 'images/grad6.jpg',];
var gradAmt = gradImg.length-1;
var i = 0;

if( i > gradAmt ) {
  i = 0;
}
screenImg.src = gradImg[i];
i++;
var timer = setTimeout(slideshow, 1000);
}
slideshow();
```

Comment: You could also use the setInterval-function, which periodically calls a function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reset `i` to `0` each time `slideshow` is called.

Move `var i = 0;` so it is outside the function.

---

Since it won't be local to the function any more, consider giving it a more explicit name, such as `slideshow_index`